# Error when trying to run template with iterating function

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have created a template in XSLT2.0 which purpose is to add a specified number of days (transportation time) to a day and return the ETA. The tricky part is that goods are not transported or delivered on weekends.

I did this template, but the test run returns an error "Cannot find matching 1-argument function named add-business-days"

```
<xsl:template name="add-period" as="xs:date">
    <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:date"/>
    <xsl:param name="period" as="xs:dayTimeDuration"/>

    <xsl:variable name="workdays" select="tokenize('Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday', ',')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new-date" select="$date + $period"/>

    <xsl:function name="local:add-business-days" as="xs:date">
        <xsl:param name="current-date" as="xs:date"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$current-date &gt; $new-date">
                <xsl:sequence select="$current-date"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="index-of($workdays, format-date($current-date, '[FNn]'))">
                <xsl:sequence select="local:add-business-days($current-date + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="local:add-business-days($current-date + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:sequence select="local:add-business-days($date)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Why is it failing, the name of the function is the correct name?

Comment: See Conal's answer for moving the `xsl:function` to the top level; also make sure you declare a namespace with prefix `local` as XSLT (contrary to XQuery) doesn't predefine that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<xsl:function>` declaration needs to be a top-level element. It should not be nested inside an `<xsl:template>` declaration.

See the [XSLT spec section on stylesheet functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#stylesheet-functions):

> An xsl:function declaration can only appear as a top-level element in
> a stylesheet module.

Comment: I see, that explains the error.
How can I solve my problem then, would it be possible to solve this using a template that calls itself?
I found some examples on this, but I cannot really get a grip around how to makes this work.

Comment: Just move the `<xsl:function>` element from its current location so that it's a child of the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element

Comment: Hi, moving the function out of the template means that the variable context is lost??

Comment: @Brca, right, if you want your function to use the variables you have in your template you need to add parameters to your function and pass the template variable values as the parameter values in the function call.

Comment: I hadn't actually reviewed your function itself; I just wanted to point out that it was misplaced. I suggest you read the relevant section of the spec for a clear understanding of how to write stylesheet functions: https://www.w3.org/TR/2021/REC-xslt20-20210330/#stylesheet-functions

Comment: I don't have time just now to review the function properly, but I will point out that the `workday` variable could be defined either as a global variable or within the body of the function itself. I don't think you need the named template; you probably only need the (recursive) function itself. My advice is to eliminate the template and move parameters to the function.